# How will this Windows Task Scheduler schedule work in the morning?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

We have a program, where the client is claiming files did not get generated when they were supposed to, and only showed up late in the day.

I'm wondering if it is because of the task scheduler schedule.

The task is scheduled to start at 12:23 PM every day and then go every 5 minutes, indefinitely.

[image]

Given that schedule, and that it is set to run daily, what happens during the hours from 00:00:00 - 12:23:00?

Does the previous day's schedule keep running into the next day because of the "indefinitely" setting?

Or since the task is set to run daily, does the previous day's schedule expire at 00:00:00, and then the next day doesn't get ANY runs until 12:23 PM?

The server in question is running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some changes in our task scheduler, to enable history, it looks like the prior day's task **does** continue over into the next day.